# xmpp 'libxml/xmlversion.h' file not found in xcode 7.1

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode7, xmmp

I'm using xmmp library in a project .When i am adding library folder in my project then i got this error `xmpp 'libxml/xmlversion.h' file not found` after at Google i get this solution Goto Projects -> Build Settings and add “`$SDKROOT/usr/include/libxml2` ” to Header search path it's work perfectly .But now new problem is arise . New three errors append . List are bellow :

```
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/Mac-Devs/Documents/Ferrakkem/DivineIosDialer/../../g729'
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_dns_free_resource_record", referenced from:
      -[XMPPSRVResolver processRecord:length:] in XMPPSRVResolver.o
  "_dns_parse_resource_record", referenced from:
      -[XMPPSRVResolver processRecord:length:] in XMPPSRVResolver.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Answer (score 4):

I solved my problem by adding  `libresolv.tdd`  at "Link Binary With Libraries".

Comment: Thanks man, I am also have a same problem. Resolved with your solution..

Answer (score 0):

For **XCode8** in my build settings, I added `/usr/local/opt/libxml2/include`, to my User Header Search Paths.

I also added `Select recursive->Yes`, from the Pull down in the same row, as you added the above search path.